# Extracting all number from string and combining them using RegEx

Tags: regex, import.io

I am using RegEx in combination with an online scraper to extract data from a website. The scraper allows you to use Reguar Expressions to extract only parts of the strings.

The strings I want to extract look like this:

```
€ 1.250.000 k.k.
€ 359.000 k.k.
€ 89.000 v.o.n.
```

The result I want to get is as follows:

```
1250000
359000
80000
```

The result needs to be stored as a number.

I am using the expression `[\d.]+` now, but that includes the period. If I remove the period from the expression, it does not take the numbers after the period.

Any ideas on that?

N.B. The scraper I am using is import.io

Comment: All you need is to replace `\D+` with an empty string. In JS, `str = str.replace(/\D+/g, '')`. Does that work for you?

Comment: The thing with the scraper is, is that I am not using any programming language to find and replace the periods. Within the scraper you have the possibility to specify a RegEx to tell the scraper which characters of the string to extract. Hope that clarifies a little.

Comment: I dont know about `import.io` and its regex flavor, but you can change the regex to something like this: `[\d.]*?\K\d+` It should give you three matches for your first line. It all depends if it works *line by line* or on the *whole file*.

Comment: have you tried changing the column type to number ?

Comment: Yes I have tried that, but then 325.000 (i.e. 325k) becomes 325.00 (i.e. 325), so unfortunately this is not an option. This is caused by the fact that here in europe the period is used as thousand separator.

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways, I explain them using both *JavaScript* and *PHP* languages.

### First approach:

[Remove all non-numeric values](https://regex101.com/r/xK6dW6/3), then all the rest is what you need:

**JavaScript:**

```js
var str = "€ 1.250.000 k.k.";
    str = str.replace(/\D+/g, '');
document.write(str);
```

**PHP:**

```
$str = "€ 1.250.000 k.k.";
echo preg_replace("/\D+/", "", $str);
```

#### [Online Demo](https://3v4l.org/kFpPP)

---

### Second approach:

Extract all numbers from string and join them together to make expected number:

**JavaScript:**

```js
var str = "€ 1.250.000 k.k.";
    str = str.match(/\d/g).join("");
document.write(str);
```

**PHP:**

```
$matches = array();
$str = "€ 1.250.000 k.k.";
$str = preg_match_all('/\d/', $str, $matches);
$str = implode("", $matches[0]);
echo $str;
```

#### [Online Demo](https://3v4l.org/lnpt9)

Comment: Thanks for the idea's, but in the scraper I cannot use any programming languages to do the replace. For now, it looks like I will have to scrape the string including the period, and do the processing at a later stage. Thanks!